# escaping issue with script that uses ssh via sshpass and runs nmap inside ssh server

Tags: bash, escaping, nmap, geany, sshpass

Problem is, when using the `sshpass` command you need to use `‘` `‘` (apostrophes) in order to input the command. When I try to use `nmap`, I'm using `hostname -I` and `awk`.
The `awk ‘{print .. ‘` apostrophe clashes with the `sshpass` apostrophe.

Is there any alternatives or ways to change that?

I want to run:

```bash
sshpass -p “pass” ssh -o Strict…=no user@ip ‘ nmap $(hostname -I | awk ‘{print $1}’) ‘
```

Comment: Use public-key authentication, and you get rid of an entirely layer of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape $ with \:

```
sshpass -p “pass” ssh user@ip "nmap \$(hostname -I | awk '{print \$1}')"
```